# Checking if linerenderer collided with a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to check if a line created by linerenderer collided with a gameobject. I tried adding boxcollider2d, edgecollider2d component to linerenderer but doesn't work. The line is moving from top to bottom. The gameobject has a boxcollider also.

[image]

**UPDATE Screenshot of gameobject inspectors**

Gameobject where linerenderer will collide to
[image]

Then in the linerenderer. I generate a line using the script
[image]

```
myLine = new GameObject();
myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    myLine.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
    lr.positionCount = 3;
    lr.startWidth = .1f;
    lr.endWidth = .1f;
    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(shapePositionValues.posA, shapePositionValues.posD, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(shapePositionValues.posB, shapePositionValues.posE, -1));
    lr.useWorldSpace = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible problems that I can think of:

### Problem 1

It is not possible for 2D and 3D colliders to collide and interact. It looks like you are using a `BoxCollider` (3D) and not a `BoxCollider2D` on that object that is selected in your screenshot. You mentioned that you tried using `BoxCollider2D` and `EdgeCollider2D` to your line, both of which are 2D colliders, which will not collide with your 3D collider.

### Problem 2

Below is a table that summarizes collider interaction (doesn't include triggers).

[image]

You'll always need at least one of the objects in a collision to have a `Rigidbody` component. Whether you have a static collider, normal `Rigidbody` or a kinematic `Rigidbody` for the other object will depend on how you are moving/manipulating objects.

If you are directly moving an object (by setting its position each frame through code), then it should be a `Rigidbody` with `IsKinematic` enabled.

If you are setting the velocity of the object or manipulating it through physics forces, it should be a regular `Rigidbody`.

If the object never moves, it should usually be a static collider (collider with no `Rigidbody`).

Comment: Tried changing linerenderer and gameobject to boxcollider2d component but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Newboy11 would you be able to screenshot the inspector for both objects that you are trying to get to collide?

Comment: Also forgot to mention that you actually need Rigidbody2D instead of Rigidbody, for the same reason that you need 2D colliders. Use `myLine.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` to add it to your line, and you'll need to manually add one to your other object.

Comment: it's working now. But the rigid body is causing the linerenderer to not move properly.  added this to the script but doesn't solve the problem. 
var linerb = myLine.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        linerb.gravityScale = 0;
        linerb.mass = 0.0001f;

Will research about rigidbody. Thanks again

Comment: How are you moving the linerenderer? Are you just updating its position through a script?